# page view controller first launch ios

Tags: ios, controller, launch, appdelegate

I have a question.
I created a Page View Controller to show a tutorial of my application. This Page View Controller is showed during 
the first launch of the application. I was adding the following code to the AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"])
    {
        //Normal flow
    }
    else
    {
        //To show the tutorial
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"HasLaunchedOnce"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

        TutorialViewController* tutorialViewController = [[TutorialViewController alloc] init];
        [self.window setRootViewController:tutorialViewController];
    }
        return YES;
}
```

My problem is that I'm getting the following error during the first lunch of the app.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
>   *** First throw call stack:

May someone give me a hand to solve this problem?

Cheers.

Comment: I guess the problem is not in the `AppDelegate.m` file. This error says you are trying to init `NSArray` object with nil-reference inside.

Comment: Add an all exception breakpoint and let us know the line when the application crashes.

Comment: It crashes in the line [self.window setRootViewController:tutorialViewController];

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice Istvan. My mistake was in the PageViewController. I replace the lines to call the view controller with:

UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];

ViewController *controller = (ViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"firstViewController"];

[self.window setRootViewController:controller];

And it worked :)

Greetings